# mvc razor view nested foreach model post null subobject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, view, nested

In my code I cannot read a nested object value on form post.

Wrog way to edit List property in one Object:

```
 @{
        var contatore = 0;

        foreach (var item in Model.Movimenti)
        {
            var movimento = item;

            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    @*Imposto gli Hidden per tutte le proprietà che devo recuperare al post*@
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => movimento.Prodotto.Descrizione, "Movimenti[" + contatore + "].Prodotto.Descrizione")

                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => movimento.Prodotto.Descrizione, "Movimenti[" + contatore + "].Prodotto.Descrizione")
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => movimento.Aum, "CurrencyDisabled", "Movimenti[" + contatore + "].AUM")</td>
            </tr>
            contatore++;
        }
    }
```

This is the correct way to edit List property in one Object:

The code:

```
@using AI.Business.Models
@model Operazione
@{    ViewBag.Title = "Simulatore"; }
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreaOperazione", "Operativita", FormMethod.Post))
{     
// Imposto gli Hidden per tutte le proprietà che devo recuperare al post
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RapportoModel.TipoRapportoId)

<table width="100%" class="display" id="Simulatore" cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="dt-head-left">Linea</th>
        <th>AUM</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Movimenti)
    </tbody>

</table>
<button id="btnSalva" name="btnSalva" type="submit" style="float: right;">Salva Operazione</button>
```

}

With the editor assuggested:

```
@model AI.Business.Models.Movimento
<tr>
<td align="left">
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Prodotto.Descrizione)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Prodotto.Descrizione)</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Aum, "CurrencyDisabled")</td>
```

And this is my object:

```
public class Movimento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProdottoModel Prodotto { get; set; }
    public decimal Aum { get; set; }
}
```

And the Object Prodotto:

```
public class ProdottoModel
{    
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
}
```

In my Actionresult the property Descrizione is null:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreaOperazione(Operazione operazione)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
            ImpostaErrore(ModelState);

        return View("PaginaSimulatore", operazione);
    }
```

Open the images:
[At my first access to the page the property Prodotto.Descrizione is populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruj8U.jpg)

[When i raise the form post event this property was sent with a null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We2M4.jpg)

Comment: At the form post I can read correctly the property AUM, but not the property Prodotto.Descrizione that is null.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: And if your getting a `NullReference` exception, its because `Prodotto` is `null`

Comment: Prodotto have a value in view, and when i raise the form post in my actionresult Prodotto is null

Comment: Because you cannot use a `foreach` loop - read the link I gave you.

Comment: I've red it, but this code works correctly for all properties like AUM: @Html.EditorFor(x => movimento.Aum, "CurrencyDisabled", "Movimenti[" + contatore + "].AUM") - For this property after the post I can see the correct value. Only for the sub-object in my sub-propery I cannot see the value. Anyway I'll test the code in your link. Thanks

Comment: Thank a lot. I've added the Hidden field to the Editor and it's work.

Comment: It does not work and never will despite what you think. If you generate a collection you must use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` and you must post back the model you originally used in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're getting any of this to work, but it's a total fluke. `HiddenFor`, for example, has no parameter that let's you specify the name value for the field. Instead, where you're trying to do that, the parameter is actually for `htmlAttributes`, which expects either an anonymous object or `IDictionary`. The only reason you aren't getting errors is because `string` is technically an `object`, but it will never do anything in this context.

The same goes for the rest of your helper calls. With `EditorFor`, in particular, the second param where you're passing `"CurrencyDisabled"`, is for specifying the editor template that should be used, and the third param is for `additionalViewData`, which just appends items to `ViewData` within the context of the editor template.

Long and short, none of this works how you think it does. Plainly and simply, if you need to work with a collection, you need to use `for` rather than `foreach`. The expression that you pass to the `*For` family of helpers is not just about identifying a property however you can get to it; it must be a *bindable* expression, i.e. something Razor can use to create a name for the form field that will line up to something on your model on post. In order for that to happen, the names must be something like `Movimenti[N].Prodotto.Descrizione`, and the only way to get that is to call the helper like:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Movimenti[i].Prodotto.Descrizione)
```

Where `i` would be the iterator from your `for` loop.